# Why do some aircraft's flight control surfaces not droop when hydraulic power is taken away?

Tags: airliner, flight-controls, hydraulic-system

Analyzing a bunch of different photos of airliners sitting at Gates, I've noticed that some have flight controls that droop (due to no hydraulic power) and sometimes they stay leveled. Why is this?

[image]

[image]

In the first image of the Japan airlines Boeing 787, the rudder and elevators clearly have no hydraulic power. Yet the ailerons are still leveled. In the second picture of the West jet Boeing 787, there seems to be no flight control droop.

This isn't just about the 787 but all aircraft in general.

Comment: @Bianfable I've looked at that question and it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I can't see how the questions are different. If you think they are you need to explain why to differentiate them.

Comment: @GdD I was asking why the same plane would have two different situations when one droops and the other doesn't.

Comment: I don't see control droop on either of those pictures.

Comment: @GdD The elevator on the top photo are drooped.

Comment: It doesn't look that way to me @Boeing787, but I'll defer to others on this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two kinds of Power Control Units used on flight controls. The PCU is the hydraulic cylinder and input control valves and linkage that drives the surface, normally two or three per surface. The input linkage operates a hydraulic spool valve that controls flow of fluid to either side of the cylinder, like in any piece of construction equipment.

Some PCUs, when you take hydraulic pressure away, open an internal valve that connects both sides of the actuator together. Also called an "idle circuit". These actuators are free to move when unpressurized, like a car shock absorber. They still have a damping function when in this state, which is important to flutter resistance for control surfaces that are not mass balanced, typical on jets with hydraulic controls.

On the ground, when all the hydraulic systems are unpressurized, a flight control will sag under its weight as it displaces the (usually 3) hydraulic actuators that are "idled" by the removal of pressure. They usually won't sag all the way to the bottom, because the mechanical input linkage starts to resist displacement of the cylinder after it moves some amount.

Other PCUs don't use an idle circuit and if there is no control input to the PCU, fluid is trapped in both sides of the cylinder and it's locked hydraulically in whatever position it's in. The surface can be made to move when unpressurized, but only if the PCU's control valve is diplaced by moving the control from the cockpit.

On the CRJs, the aileron PCUs (two per surface) are non-idling. When unpressurized, the ailerons are rigid at neutral as if bolted in place. However you can move them if you move the control wheel to displace the internal hydraulic input valve.

However the Elevator (and rudder) PCUs are idling type, and when unpressurized, the elevator surface will slowly sag about half way down until it starts trying to backdrive the mechanical linkage due to the input linkage geometry.

Comment: Is their a benefit to the rudder and elevators being the idling type vs non idling type?

Comment: I don't recall the specific reason one or the other is used. I think it allows you to take credit for the unit as a flutter damper when it's hydraulic system is unpressurized.

Comment: so would you say that one of those photos is a plane receiving maintenance services? Cause the other 787 seems to have all the flight controls locked in place.

Comment: The WestJet one has elevators sagging a bit as well. You can see if you zoom in.

Comment: There is a third type that requires positive flow to move. Compare my neighbor's John deer tractor to my iFarmall. When shutdown he can lower the hydraulics with the valve control, and given a day or two it will leak through the valve and settle on its own. But my Farmall will stay elevated indefinitely, altering the control valve position does nothing without pump flow. I have positive down pressure (beyond gravity), he has lift pressure only but that allows float (can be good for smoothing). Anyhow the Farmall has been parked over 6 months with elevated hydraulics, no sag.

Comment: That a non-idling actuator.  In the airplane the cylinder and control valving and input linkage are all in the same unit.

Answer (score 2):

The control surfaces do not droop during power or hydraulic shut off technically because the isolation or switching valves switch to their default state which blocks pressure and return ports, thus the actuators are locked in position.

When the controls droop, the iso or switching valves port pressure to return, thus the flaps fall under gravity.

Why some planes are in the "droop" state while at the gate might be a maintenance reason. If you are doing maintenance you want the hydraulics powered down (pressure vented to return, thus drooped). My best guess.